# Overlaying background sound

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

we are having problem with our background sound. If the sound is on when we change view and then go back to the menu it adds another loop of sound. If the sound is muted when we go back it starts again. Please help. This is my code.

```
//  Meny.m

#import "Meny.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface Meny () {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayerBG;
}
@end 

@implementation Meny
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"TestSwoong" ofType:@"wav"];   
    audioPlayerBG = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error:NULL];
    audioPlayerBG.numberOfLoops = -1;
    audioPlayerBG.volume = 0.5;
    [audioPlayerBG play];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

// LjudKnapp stop
- (IBAction)stopBG:(id)sender {
    [playBG setHidden:NO];
    [pauseBG setHidden:YES];
    [audioPlayerBG stop];
}

// LjudKnapp play
- (IBAction)playBG:(id)sender {
    [pauseBG setHidden:NO];
    [playBG setHidden:YES];
    [audioPlayerBG play];
}
```

Comment: You need to fix your code tags, it's a bit unreadable as-is

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to brush up on what classes and instances are. Understanding classes and instances is fundamental if you're going to do object-oriented programming, which is what you do when you use Objective-C.

> we change view and then go back to the menu it adds another loop of sound

That phrase suggests that when you "go back", you are not actually *going back* to the *already existing* Meny instance - instead, you are creating *another* Meny instance. So now, you see, you have two of them! Well, each Meny instance has its own AVAudioPlayer, which starts playing when the Meny instance is created — so now you have two audio players, and that's why you hear two loops playing simultaneously.